# Make a copy of my current desktop state

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have just installed Windows 7 (for the 10th time),
installed all my required software, 
made all the little tweaks that I want in Windows.

I want to be able to save this condition of my computer so that in the future when things go kaput, and I reformat, I can get back to this state without having to install and tweak everything again..

Possible?

Comment: There are dozens upon dozens of applications that can image your hdd tools.  Your basically asking how to image your hdd.

Comment: re: close vote - I see this as a simple 'how do i do x?' question, rather than software rec. Admittedly it could have done with more research, but the answer is available right within Windows itself.

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel > System & Security > Backup Your Computer > Create a System Image.

Have a backup drive ready-connected to save it to.

*From Microsoft Help*

**What is a system image?**

> A system image is an exact copy of a drive. By default, a system image includes the drives required for Windows to run. It also includes Windows and your system settings, programs, and files. You can use a system image to restore the contents of your computer if your hard disk or computer ever stops working. When you restore your computer from a system image, it's a complete restoration—you can't choose individual items to restore, and all of your current programs, system settings, and files are replaced with the contents of the system image.
>
> Although this type of backup includes your personal files, we recommend that you back up your files regularly using Windows Backup so that you can restore individual files and folders as needed. When you set up Windows Backup, you can let Windows choose what to back up, which will include a system image, or you can select the items that you want to back up and whether you want to include a system image. For more information about setting up Windows Backup, see Back up your files.
>
> If your computer contains several drives or partitions, you can create a system image that includes all of them by following the steps in Back up your programs, system settings, and files.

Comment: Is this included by default in all "editions" of Windows 7?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, yes; it's also in Vista [didn't check if all versions] & 8

Comment: I use it as 'belt & braces' I have Acronis running to a local server, Backblaze for offsite, & a one-off image of each machine just in case.

Answer (score -1):

The way I do this is to use a virtual machine (such as Hyper-V or VMWare).  There are many virtual machine (VM) solutions that are available free for personal use.

Once you have the VM solution installed on your local machine, then you install the OS on top of this.  Then the whole installation becomes just another file that you can move and backup to your hearts content. You can also evolve the environment, suspend the virtual machine and then make incremental backups of your environment evolution.